# Referencing external val in actor class

Tags: scala, closures, akka

Is it prohibited by design or am I doing something wrong?

```
val ext = 1

class Test extends Actor {
  def receive = { case _ => println(ext) }
}

try {
  val sys = ActorSystem("lol")
  sys.actorOf(Props[Test], "test") ! true
} catch {
  case e: Throwable => println(e)
}
```

once I send a message to `Test` I get an exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no matching constructor found on class HelloAkkaScala$Test$1 for arguments []`.
I don't have this exception if I don't reference `ext` inside of `Test` class.
I'm using Akka 2.3.4

Comment: Check out update on my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in accessing `val` (not `var` or any other mutable state) defined outside of the actor.

Just tried to run your example code in Akka 2.3.5 and it works fine. You probably have a typo somwhere in your original code.

**UPDATE**

Looking closer at the error you are getting it seems like you've defined `Test` class inside some other class.

In this case *inner class* (`Test`) will receive reference to *outer class* behind the scenes in order to be able to close on it's members (`ext`).

This also means that constructor of the *inner class* will take reference to the *outer class* (syntactic sugar hides this).

This also explains why you are getting the error (you pass 0 args to constructor but there actually some hidden ones that you are not supplying).

Here is the example that reproduces this:

```
class Boot {

  val ext = 1

  class Test extends Actor {
    def receive = { case _ => println(ext) }
  }

  try {
    val sys = ActorSystem("lol")
    sys.actorOf(Props[Test], "test") ! true
  } catch {
    case e: Throwable => println(e)
  }

}

object Boot extends App {

  new Boot

}
```

... and here is a quick workaround (in this case I make `Test` and `ext` "static" by moving them to companion object, but you can achieve similar results by referencing `ext` as a member of some other instance, passed to constructor):

```
class Boot {

  import Boot.Test

  try {
    val sys = ActorSystem("lol")
    sys.actorOf(Props[Test], "test") ! true
  } catch {
    case e: Throwable => println(e)
  }

}

object Boot extends App {

  val ext = 1

  class Test extends Actor {
    def receive = { case _ => println(ext) }
  }

  new Boot

}
```